# How to code constrained randomisation ( 2 factors)

Tags: r

I want to randomize one factor and another factor should be randomized within the first factor. How do I do that?

```
id <- rep(c(10,20,30), each=3)
visit <- rep(1:3,3)
df <- data.frame(id, visit)
df
  id visit
1 10     1
2 10     2
3 10     3
4 20     1
5 20     2
6 20     3
7 30     1
8 30     2
9 30     3
```

it could for example look like this:
  id visit

```
1 20     1
2 20     3
3 20     2
4 30     3
5 30     2
6 30     1
7 10     1
8 10     2
9 10     3
```

Here is code to randomise each id, but I dont know how to put this in a function and then also randomise the second column.

```
uniq <- unique(df[,1]) %>% sample()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `sample` by `unique` id, using `sapply`.

```
set.seed(42)
dat$visit <- unlist(lapply(unique(dat$id), function(i) sample(dat$visit[dat$id == i])))
dat
#   id visit
# 1 10     2
# 2 10     1
# 3 10     3
# 4 20     3
# 5 20     1
# 6 20     2
# 7 30     3
# 8 30     1
# 9 30     2
```

***Edit:*** To sample also the order of the IDs, you could sample the rows afterwards, `dat[sample(nrow(dat)), ]`. Or all combined in a `transform()`:

```
set.seed(42)
transform(dat,
          visit=unlist(lapply(unique(dat$id), function(i) 
            sample(dat$visit[dat$id == i]))))[sample(nrow(dat)), ]
#   id visit
# 8 30     3
# 7 30     2
# 4 20     1
# 1 10     1
# 5 20     2
# 2 10     3
# 9 30     1
# 3 10     2
# 6 20     3
```

To sample the id ranges with sampled visits, you could use a `by` approach.

```
set.seed(42)
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$id, function(x) {
  transform(x, visit=sample(visit))
})[sample(seq(unique(dat$id)))])
#      id visit
# 30.7 30     2
# 30.8 30     3
# 30.9 30     1
# 20.4 20     1
# 20.5 20     2
# 20.6 20     3
# 10.1 10     1
# 10.2 10     3
# 10.3 10     2
```

*Explanation:* The `by` splits the data at `"id"`s into a list of data frames, that can be `transform`ed as above, and after `sample`ing the order `rbind`ed into the resulting data frame.

---

*Data:*

```
(dat <- expand.grid(visit=1:3, id=(1:3)*10)[2:1])
#   id visit
# 1 10     1
# 2 10     2
# 3 10     3
# 4 20     1
# 5 20     2
# 6 20     3
# 7 30     1
# 8 30     2
# 9 30     3
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf! But I also want to randomize the order of the id....

Comment: Ok, but I want the same id to stay together! for example, 30,30,30,20,20,20,10,10,10

Comment: @user11916948 An interesting, see new edit. Does this work for you?